# Enabling use of WebAuthenticationBroker with SoundCloud

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, soundcloud

In order to use WebAuthenticationBroker (Microsoft's WinRT signon library), I have to set the protocol to ms-app:// which works fine when I invoke it from a web browser.

When invoked inside a WinRT app, via WebAuthenticationBroker I get a protocol error (422).

Has anyone done this successfully?

Some sample code would be very, very useful :)

Here's our code: (our key replaced by --------- of course)

```
        String URL = "https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("-----------------------------") +
            "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("ms-app://rewritez") +
            "&response_type=code&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("non-expiring");


        string url = URL;

        Uri startUri = new Uri(url);
        Uri endUri = new Uri("https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token?");

        try
        {
            WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult =
                await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle, startUri, endUri);

            if (webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                string token = webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData;
                // now you have the token
            }
            else if (webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
            {
                // do something when the request failed
            }
            else
            {
                // do something when an unknown error occurred
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            int i = 43; // statement here just so we can set a breakpoint for debuggin
            // do something when an exception occurred
        }
```

Comment: Which stack are you using (HTML/JS or C#/XAML)? Can you share the code that's causing the error?

Comment: We're using C#/XAML.  Code added to original question.

Comment: " I have to set the protocol to ms-app:// which works fine when I invoke it from a web browser."  What do you mean by that? I see you set the `redirect_uri` in the API URL but your `EndUri` points to the token URL which I believe you use after the user has authorized your app and want to make API calls using the token you received and saved. Just curious because I have similar problems, whereas my WebAuthBroker won't respond to ms-app:// protocol callbacks.

Comment: Update on this:  Doesn't matter whether I use ms-app://xxxxx as the End URI or if I use http://developers.soundcloud.com/callback.html, I'm getting inconsistent results.  I *have* been able to login (sometimes) but most of the time I get a 422 protocol error.

Comment: I also sometimes get this error. What I believe to be the cause is that if you either (1) type in your credentials incorrectly a few times, or (2) have been logging in too frequently, then normally SoundCloud will require you to re-authenticate but with a captcha. For some reason, the web authentication broker isn't able to handle this case, it doesn't even display the captcha, and the whole process fails. Try logging in with facebook, which bypasses the captcha. Then it'll work. (Not really a solution, but it's just what I've observed.)